# Different error messages at different times "SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position " at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)"

Tags: python, node.js, arrays, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I'm new to JavaScript and AWS. And I invoked a separate Lambda function (Let's say child lambda) from a middle line of the main Lambda function (Let's say parent lambda) and use the returned value from the child lambda in the parent lambda.

My child lambda is implemented in Python 3.6 and parent lambda is implemented in Node.js 12.x.

I have a 3d array assigned to variable 'img' in the parent lambda. If a condition satisfies I invoke the child lambda by passing the Payload as 3d 'img' array. 
In the child lambda I create an image using the array values, preprocess the image (add some filters and crop the image) convert back to a 3d array by below code.

```
imageList = croppedImage.tolist()
```

And then swap some elements in it using below code (Please note that the size of imageList array is 224x224x3)

```
for i in range(224):
   for j in range(224):
       a=imageList[i][j][0]
       imageList[i][j][0]=imageList[i][j][2]
       imageList[i][j][2]=a
```

and then return it to the parent lambda using below code.

```
return {
      "returnArray": imageList
}
```

And finally replace the 'img' variable with the returned array.

The code block in the parent lambda is below. I used Line 1 to convert it a JSON object.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'ap-southeast-2';
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

exports.handler = async (event, ctx, callback) => {
    //////////code lines for other operations////////////

    let img = //Line A - 3d array with RGB values of an image;
    let body1;
    if(condition){
        console.log("BEGIN");
        var params = {
                FunctionName: 'childFunction', // child lambda function written in Pyton 3.6
                InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
                Payload: JSON.stringify({ "sendImg" : img})
            };
            lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                } else {
                console.log('Returned '+ data.Payload); //Line B
                let body1;
                if(typeof(data.Payload) == 'object') {
                    body1 = data.Payload;
                } else {
                    body1 = JSON.parse(data.Payload); //Line 1
                }
                img = body1["returnArray"];
                }
            }).promise();
    }
    ////////Rest of the code///////////////////////
};
```

This is the python lambda function (Child lambda)

```
import json
import cv2
import numpy as np

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    array=event['sendImg']
    for i in range(224):
        for j in range(224):
            a=array[i][j][0]
            array[i][j][0]=array[i][j][2]
            array[i][j][2]=a
    new_image = np.array(array, np.uint8)
    
    image = new_image
    image1 = image.copy()
    lab = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
    l,a,b = cv2.split(lab)

    #perform thresholding
    m,thresh = cv2.threshold(a,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    i=0
    maxArea=0
    for c in contours:
        i+=1
        areaC = cv2.contourArea(c)
        if maxArea<areaC:
            maxArea=areaC
            maxIndex=i
        
    i=0
    image3=image.copy()
    for c in contours:
        i+=1
        if i==maxIndex:
            rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
            (x, y), (width, height), angle = rect
            box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
            box = np.int0(box)
            cv2.drawContours(image3,[box],0,(0,0,0),-1)
    
    image4=image.copy()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image3, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    m,mask = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    mean = cv2.mean(image4, mask=mask)
    diff = [127-mean[0],127-mean[1],127-mean[2]]

    rows,cols,c = image.shape
    image5=image.copy()

    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            k = image5[i,j]
            if(k[0]+diff[0]>255):
                image5[i,j][0] = 255
            elif(k[0]+diff[0]<0):
                image5[i,j][0] = 0
            else:
                image5[i,j][0] = image5[i,j][0]+diff[0]
                
            if(k[1]+diff[1]>255):
                image5[i,j][1] = 255
            elif(k[1]+diff[1]<0):
                image5[i,j][1] = 0
            else:
                image5[i,j][1] = image5[i,j][1]+diff[1]
                
            if(k[2]+diff[2]>255):
                image5[i,j][2] = 255
            elif(k[2]+diff[2]<0):
                image5[i,j][2] = 0
            else:
                image5[i,j][2] = image5[i,j][2]+diff[2]

    #crop
    image2 = image5.copy()
    lab = cv2.cvtColor(image2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
    l,a,b = cv2.split(lab)

    #perform thresholding
    m,thresh = cv2.threshold(a,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    image6 = image5.copy()
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cv2.drawContours(image6, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 1)

    i=0
    maxArea=0
    for c in contours:
        i+=1
        areaC = cv2.contourArea(c)
        if maxArea<areaC:
            maxArea=areaC
            maxIndex=i
        
    i=0
    image7=image5.copy()
    image8=image5.copy()
    for c in contours:
        i+=1
        if i==maxIndex:
            rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
            (x, y), (width, height), angle = rect
            x=round(x)
            y=round(y)
            width=round(width)
            height=round(height)
            box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
            box = np.int0(box)
            cv2.drawContours(image7,[box],0,(0,255,0),2)
            src_pts = box.astype("float32")
            dst_pts = np.array([[0, height-1],
                                [0, 0],
                                [width-1, 0],
                                [width-1, height-1]], dtype="float32")
            M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src_pts, dst_pts)
            warped = cv2.warpPerspective(image8, M, (width, height))
            croppedImage = cv2.resize(warped, (224,224), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    imageList = croppedImage.tolist()
    for i in range(224):
        for j in range(224):
            a=imageList[i][j][0]
            imageList[i][j][0]=imageList[i][j][2]
            imageList[i][j][2]=a
    print("returnArray ",imageList) #Line 3
    return {
        "returnArray": imageList
    }
```

**Issue:**
When running the program with the same 'img' array (Line A) at different times, Line 1 gives different error messages. Sometimes it doesn't give any error messages and complete the program successfully.

Some of the error messages are below.

Error message at a time -

```
{
    "errorType": "SyntaxError",
    "errorMessage": "Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 1****",
    "code": "SyntaxError",
    "message": "Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 1",
    "time": "2021-07-19T09:50:14.678Z",
    "stack": [
        "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 1",
        "    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)",
        "    at Response.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:81:30)",
        "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:369:18)",
        "    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)",
        "    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)",
        "    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)",
        "    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
        "    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
        "    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
        "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)"
    ]
}
```

Error message at another time -

```
{
    "errorType": "SyntaxError",
    "errorMessage": "Unexpected token , in JSON at position 3",
    "code": "SyntaxError",
    "message": "Unexpected token , in JSON at position 3",
    "time": "2021-07-19T09:10:41.553Z",
    "stack": [
        "SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 3",
        "    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)",
        "    at Response.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:81:30)",
        "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:369:18)",
        "    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)",
        "    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)",
        "    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)",
        "    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
        "    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
        "    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
        "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)"
    ]
}
```

You can see that the token and the position is different in above two errors.

Sometimes it doesn't give any error messages and complete the program successfully.

I printed the output 3d array in the child lambda and returned 3d array (data.Payload) in the parent lambda (Line B).

Line 3 in the python lambda (child lambda) prints the correct 3d array.
Output at Line 3  in the python lambda - 
returnArray  [[[113, 111, 110], [66, 60, 55], [51, 44, 38], [53, 44, 38], [59, 48, 42], [63, 53, 47], [68, 61, 56], [73, 62, 56], [74, 64, 58], [75, 65, 59], [80, 70, 64], [84, 75, 67], [86, 77, 68],...

It's correct.

But Line B gives a different result.
Sometimes output of data.Payload has missed a certain part of the array at the beginning.

Some of the example outputs are below (Line B output).
Returned [131, 69, 20], [130, 70, 28], [125, 69, 34], [118, 59, 26], [81, 22, 0],...

Returned 133], [186, 146, 110], [172, 125, 86], [123, 72, 43], [88, 37, 14], [150, 100, 54], [180, 126, 74], [179, 121, 64],...

But it should be;
Returned {"returnArray": [[[113, 111, 110], [66, 60, 55], [51, 44, 38], [53, 44, 38], [59, 48, 42], [63, 53, 47], [68, 61, 56],...

Why returned array from the child lambda sometimes different in the parent lambda?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems like you are not always receiving a valid JSON from your first function and thats causing the exception.
Try spliting this line.
       body1 = JSON.parse(data.Payload); //Line 1
into 
       body1 = data.Payload; //Line 1
       body1 = JSON.parse(body1);
And try to see what are you getting there. Maybe is a conection error or your first function is not working properly.

Comment: Probably because of invalid JSON, add a `console.log(data && data.Payload);` before this line  `body1 = JSON.parse(data.Payload); //Line 1`, and check the data.Payload is valid or not, You may update the console.log results to the original post aswell, we can help

Comment: @RubénVega I've edited the question with some results. Could you take a look again? Thanks

Comment: @majurageerthan  I've edited the question with some console.log results. Could you take a look again? Thanks

Comment: As I suspected It seem that the problems is in that other function. What you are fetching from that is not a valid JSON. You should post that python3 code too.

Comment: @MalieshaKalutota, I also agree with RubénVega, It will be great adding a log to your python lamda before return for checking what it is returning

Comment: I've edited the question with the python code and it's print result. Could you take a look again?

Comment: Did you reproduce the error? I mean, when you get a NON VALID JSON in the JS code, what  did you get in the python print?
I'm not an expert on python, but you could try to return a JSON string instead of the list.
[link](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-convert-a-list-to-a-json-array-in-python)

Comment: @RubénVega Yes, I reproduced the error. Python 'print' statement at Line 3 prints the correct array (I've add the result in the original post). Although it gives the correct array in the python code, it give invalid JSON in JS code. Why is that?

Comment: I would try to return the answer in JSON, like is posted on the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html).
`    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": json.dumps({data})
    }`
If this doesn't work I would change the question for something like "Lambda function handler error in Python" To see if this reach someone how can help you more.

Comment: @RubénVega I returned the array in JSON. It worked. Thank you